# My Circular Queue implementation is not working properly

Tags: c

I have created a program to implement a Circular Queue with insert, delete and display. The insertion is working fine and the deletion too but once I try to enter numbers after deletion, nothing is displayed. Here is my source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 5
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;
int queue[SIZE];
void enqueue(int item);
int dequeue();
void display();
void main()
{
    int item, choice, cont = 1;
    clrscr();

    while(cont == 1)
    {
        printf("\n1.Enqueue into queue.\n");
        printf("\n2.Dequeue from queue.\n");
      printf("\n3.display quesue elements\n");

        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter the value of item: ");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                enqueue(item);
                break;

            case 2:
                item = dequeue();
                if(item != NULL)
                {
                    printf("\nItem dequeued: %d\n",item);
                }
                break;
         case 3:
                display();
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nInvalid choice.\n");
                break;
        }

        printf("\nDo you want to continue (1/0): ");
        scanf("%d",&cont);
    }

    getch();
}


void enqueue(int item)
{

  if(front==0 && rear==SIZE-1)
    printf("\n Queue OverFlow Occured");
  else if(front==-1 && rear==-1)
  {
      front=rear=0;
      queue[rear]=item;

  }
  else if(rear==SIZE-1 && front!=0)
  {
    rear=0;
    queue[rear]=item;
  }
    else
   {
      rear++;
      queue[rear]=item;
   }


}
int dequeue()
{
    int item = NULL;
    if(front == -1 && rear == -1)
    {
        printf("\nQueue is empty. Dequeue not possible.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        item = queue[front];
        queue[front] = NULL;

        if(front == rear)
        {
            front = -1;
            rear = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            front = front + 1;
        }

   }
    return(item);
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    if(front==-1)
      printf("\n No elements to display");
    else
    {
      printf("\n The queue elements are:\n ");
      for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
      {
          printf("\t %d",queue[i]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "circular queue"??

Comment: @Olaf A circular buffer I suppose.

Comment: @Olaf I'm assuming it's an array that implements circular shifts.

Comment: Ok, a queue using a ring buffer.

Comment: SUGGESTION: step through the code in your debugger.  Set breakpoints in "enqueue()" and "dequeue()".  Look at the relevant variables.  Ask yourself "Is this what I expected to see?" Q: What compiler/debugger do you have?

Comment: "What is a "circular queue"??" -- It's (obviously) a queue implemented as a circular buffer. If that still isn't clear enough for you, see https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-circular-queue or any of hundreds of google hits.

Comment: Your code could be much simpler if rear pointed to the next slot to fill rather than the last filled; then an empty queue has front == rear and no need for the special -1/-1 state. Use (rear = rear + 1) % SIZE to advance, which handles wraparound without having to explicitly check for it.

Comment: thank you sir @JimBalter

Comment: Also, get rid of the NULL stuff ... NULL is 0 and that's not allowing you to use 0 a data.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code its working fine.

> Few suggestions don't use conio.h [clrscr(), and getch()] these are not standards.

Try the code below it worked for me fine.

## CODE

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define SIZE 5
    int front = -1;
    int rear = -1;
    int queue[SIZE];
    void enqueue(int item);
    int dequeue();
    void display();
    int main()
    {
        int item, choice, cont = 1;

        while(cont == 1)
        {
            printf("\n1.Enqueue into queue.\n");
            printf("\n2.Dequeue from queue.\n");
          printf("\n3.display quesue elements\n");

            printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
            scanf("%d",&choice);

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    printf("\nEnter the value of item: ");
                    scanf("%d",&item);
                    enqueue(item);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    item = dequeue();
                    if(item != NULL)
                    {
                        printf("\nItem dequeued: %d\n",item);
                    }
                    break;
             case 3:
                    display();
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("\nInvalid choice.\n");
                    break;
            }

            printf("\nDo you want to continue (1/0): ");
            scanf("%d",&cont);
        }

        printf("");
        return 0;
    }


    void enqueue(int item)
    {

      if(front==0 && rear==SIZE-1)
        printf("\n Queue OverFlow Occured");
      else if(front==-1 && rear==-1)
      {
          front=rear=0;
          queue[rear]=item;

      }
      else if(rear==SIZE-1 && front!=0)
      {
        rear=0;
        queue[rear]=item;
      }
        else
       {
          rear++;
          queue[rear]=item;
       }


    }
    int dequeue()
    {
        int item = NULL;
        if(front == -1 && rear == -1)
        {
            printf("\nQueue is empty. Dequeue not possible.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            item = queue[front];
            queue[front] = NULL;

            if(front == rear)
            {
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                front = front + 1;
            }

       }
        return(item);
    }
    void display()
    {
        int i;
        if(front==-1)
          printf("\n No elements to display");
        else
        {
          printf("\n The queue elements are:\n ");
          for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
          {
              printf("\t %d",queue[i]);
          }
        }

    }
```

## OUTPUT

```
    Do you want to continue (1/0): 1

    1.Enqueue into queue.

    2.Dequeue from queue.

    3.display quesue elements

    Enter your choice: 3

     The queue elements are:
       5   5
    Do you want to continue (1/0): 1

    1.Enqueue into queue.

    2.Dequeue from queue.

    3.display quesue elements

    Enter your choice: 1

    Enter the value of item: 43

    Do you want to continue (1/0): 1

    1.Enqueue into queue.

    2.Dequeue from queue.

    3.display quesue elements

    Enter your choice: 3

     The queue elements are:
       5   5   43
    Do you want to continue (1/0): 1

    1.Enqueue into queue.

    2.Dequeue from queue.

    3.display quesue elements

    Enter your choice: 2

    Item dequeued: 5

    Do you want to continue (1/0): 1

    1.Enqueue into queue.

    2.Dequeue from queue.

    3.display quesue elements

    Enter your choice: 3

     The queue elements are:
       5   43
    Do you want to continue (1/0):
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my problem still persists. My exact problem is that once I enter 5 elements in the queue and then delete an element and then again insert one, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Fully Functional updated code. I pasted code on Ideone.com Link is [link to code](http://ideone.com/WAx8Ju)

If you don't understand anything just ask. I tried to explain it using comments. And now it is not having any problem that you were facing .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define SIZE 5

int front = -1;
int rear = -1;
int queue[SIZE];
void enqueue(int item);
int dequeue();
void display();
void main()
{
    int item, choice, cont = 1;
    clrscr();

    while(cont == 1)
    {
    printf("\n1.Enqueue into queue.\n");
    printf("\n2.Dequeue from queue.\n");
  printf("\n3.display quesue elements\n");

    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter the value of item: ");
            scanf("%d",&item);
            enqueue(item);
            break;



       case 2:
                item = dequeue();
                if(item != NULL)
                {
                    printf("\nItem dequeued: %d\n",item);
                }
                break;
         case 3:
                display();
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nInvalid choice.\n");
                break;
        }

        printf("\nDo you want to continue (1/0): ");
        scanf("%d",&cont);
    }

    getch();
    }


    void enqueue(int item)
    {
    int temp = (rear+1)%SIZE;    //EDIT HERE
      if(temp == front){
        printf("\n Queue OverFlow Occured"); 
          return;
}
      else if(front==-1 )
      {
          front=rear=0;
          queue[rear]=item;
          return;
      }
      else{
            rear = (rear+1)%SIZE;    // EDIT HERE
            queue[rear%SIZE]=item;
       }
    }
    int dequeue()
    {
        int item = NULL;
        if(front == rear)   //     modified condition
        {
            printf("\nQueue is empty. Dequeue not possible.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            item = queue[front];
            queue[front] = NULL;
            front++;                                    // front must be incremented
            if(front > rear)                           
            {
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
            }
       }
        return(item);
    }
    void display()
    {
        int i;
        if(front==-1)
          printf("\n No elements to display");
        else
        {
          printf("\n The queue elements are:\n ");
          for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
          {
              printf("%d\t",queue[i]);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming you know the working of circular queue, if not wikipedia explains it very well just go through it.

Comment: When I run this code, it says Undefined Symbol 'NULL'

Comment: I corrected it, it did not have #include<stdio.h > :)

Comment: is it working now ?  turbo c++ is obsolete one , you can try codeblocks .

Answer (score 1):

Thats a rather confusing code. Since the idea is for the queue to be circular, trying to determine if the queue is full by checking the position of `front` and `rear` can be really tricky, aswell as trying to make decisions based on `front` being higher than `rear` etc. You can avoid all that. A third variable keeping track of the length of the queue will make your life a whole lot easier.

Try this implementation instead:

```
#define SIZE 5
int queue[SIZE];
int read = 0, write = 0, size = 0;

void enqueue(int item)
{
    if (size >= SIZE)
    {
        printf("Queue is full");
        return;
    }
    queue[write] = item;

    write = (write + 1) % SIZE;
    size++;
}

int dequeue()
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return 0;
    }
    read %= SIZE;
    size--;
    return queue[read++];
}
```